# What's a direct or quickest proof of simple zeros lift to factorizations lift?

Tags: field-theory, valuation-theory, hensels-lemma

Is there a direct proof that for a valued  field $(F,v)$, the existence of lifts of simple roots in $k_v$ (the residue field) to $\mathcal{O}_v$ (the valuation subring) implies that factorizations in $k_v[x]$ lift to factorizations in $\mathcal{O}_v[x]$?

By 'direct proof', I mean a proof that does not use one of the equivalent characterizations of Henselianity. Alternatively, a relatively short proof of the implication that uses one equivalent characterization as a lemma would also be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: It might be better to explain that $k$ is a residue field of $\mathcal O$... But/and, also, this lifting does not quite work if $\mathcal O$ is not complete. Can you clarify?